# How to print typed parse tree

Tags: ocaml

`-dparsetree` can be used to print untyped parse tree, but how can one print typed AST in OCaml? I looked into the `typing` directory in the source code, it seems that some functions can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-dtypedtree`.  It is a newer feature than `-dparsetree` and introduced from 4.01.0. You need to upgrade your compiler if `ocamlc` does not have it.

Unfortunately `-dtypedtree` does not show the type information of the typed AST.  I am afraid there is no option or tool to print it with type information currently.  Probably since printing all the type info attached to the subnodes is too hard to read, I am afraid. For example, even a simple code `let f x = x + 1` has the following typed AST:

```
let (f : int -> int) =
  (fun (x : int) ->  
    (( ( (+) : int -> int -> int) (x : int) : int -> int) (1 : int) : int) : int -> int)
```

The best way is to write your own printer of typed AST which only prints types of your interest.

Comment: Thx! seems that -dtypedtree does not carry type information. For example, by looking at what ``-dtypedtree`` prints out, I cannot know "let f x = x + 1" has type ``val f: int -> int``. Is there a way to see the parse tree as well as type information? simply let compiler to infer ``.mli`` file cannot do this.

Comment: Yes, `-dtypedtree` unfortunately drops inferred types.  I extended my answer.